# How to create a static method factory in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm creating a static method factory function in typescript. I did it in ES6. It's working fine and getting the result as I expecting. There is a type-casting issue when I use it in TypeScript. Could you help to fix that or suggest a different design?

#### JavaScript

REPL: https://repl.it/@RenjithV/NeatTepidBugs

```js
class EventController {
  static create () {
    console.log('event created')
  }
}

class MessageController {
  static read () {
    console.log('message read')
  }
}

const controllers = {
  'event': EventController,
  'message': MessageController
}

function factory (controller, method) {
  return controllers[controller][method]() // Working fine
}

const createEvent = factory('event', 'create') // event created
const readMessage = factory('message', 'read') // message read
```

#### TypeScript

REPL: https://repl.it/@RenjithV/EuphoricFeistyUtility

```
class EventController {
  static create () {
    console.log('event created')
  }
}

class MessageController {
  static read () {
    console.log('message read')
  }
}

const controllers = {
  'event': EventController,
  'message': MessageController
}

function factory (controller: string, method: string) {
  return controllers[controller][method]() // How to fix this? How to create a method factory like this?
}

const createEvent = factory('event', 'create')
const readMessage = factory('message', 'read')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class EventController {
  public static create () {
    console.log('event created')
    return true
  }
}

class MessageController {
  public static read () {
    console.log('message read')
  }
}

type Controllers = {
    event: typeof EventController
    message: typeof MessageController
}
type OnlyStatic<T> = Exclude<T, 'prototype'>

const controllers: Controllers = {
  'event': EventController,
  'message': MessageController
}

function factory<K extends keyof Controllers, M extends OnlyStatic<keyof Controllers[K]>>(controller: K, method: M): Controllers[K][M] {
  return controllers[controller][method]
}

const createEvent = factory('event', 'create')
const readMessage = factory('message', 'read')

const bool = createEvent()
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=27#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBuBTAdgFwMIHs0CdMhER2gG8AoaaABwFcAjEAS2GglTFWemB0Q8WgAKAJSkKlbtgj5EAOhCYA5oIDkiJGm69+AExXDxlXqho5k0VDhqJxAXzL2yoSDACyiKGEWIsufIWJySloGLjYOLm0dIVEgiWApGXklVQBbDwgvASj9OwcyMlQATyoBX0t-IhgAXjEJaHUUVAAuCxLETAAzOA0MbAqCIkNodM9vVuLSruh3MZ9+vEGcfMmBAHlkECKAZXZOYAAeABUAPmha2AAPUBodRGOAGmgVKjxUTFWVE4KE5DZJPxLCCtcqLAI1OrPRpoFStBBNUGVHAPcQqUaZbywmYZLKIpb5MidGjIYCcbDQTpgUmYHBFA4AaQal1QKB0MAA1ogitM8eCnq4mSzkGzoBstrsIodOdzuryqgBtekAXROJ0EvwGAVa9Ke6VQAAtMDpWq5hCCFkiIIqlfLXErIcZTOYNWCFS6kTa9YadEqCb9-jw+Cz4ZpapTqbTVNDUConipA-xcv7UNAorMMQIw1T3pG0TjMXGcgYnFIU3RMPhzlog4gQ6gREA)

## Brief explanation

```
// generic calling is not allowed as typescript
// doesn't yet know what arguments you gonna pass to factory
// return actual function instead of function return value
controllers[controller][method]

// extending typescript Exclude utility
// removes prototype key from string union
// because class by default has static prototype method
// Exclude<"some" | "other", "other"> => "some"

type OnlyStatic<T> = Exclude<T, 'prototype'>

// assign keys of Controllers to K
// "event", "message"
K extends keyof Controllers

// assign keys of EventController if K is "event"
// assign keys of MessageController if K is "message"
M extends OnlyStatic<keyof Controllers[K>
```

## Suggestion